# Obtener los digitos de un numero- python

Tags: python

estoy intentando obtener los números de dos dígitos que son iguales al doble del producto de los dígitos, tengo este código pero me aparece un error. Se que probablemente se encuentra en como obtener los digitos 1 y 2. Si quito la sentencia if y los numeros 1-2 se imprime mis digitos del 10 al 99 en listas por separado, pero de ese numero necesito sacar sus digitos para poder aplicar mi sentencia if. Apenas estoy aprendiendo, espero puedan apoyarme

```
  for i in range(10, 100):
      list = [i]
      numero1 = str(i[0])
      numero2 = str(i[1])
      if numero1 != 0 and numero2 != 0:
        if (numero1*numero2)== (i / 2):
          print(str(i))
```

Comment: **|1|**- ¿Para qué sirve esto `list = [i]`? **|2|**- ¿Para qué intentas convertir `i` en string `str(i[0]) ` y obviamente `i` no es una lista por lo que no tiene un elemento `i[0]` ni `i[1]`. **|3|**- Si `i` empieza en `10` y termina en `100` ¿para qué necesitas esto `if numero1 != 0 and numero2 != 0`?. **|4|**- Un string multiplicado por otro string da error.

Comment: Hola! lo que quiero es que los numeros que aparecen del 10 al 100, obtenga los dos digitos por separado. Pensé en hacerlos con una lista y separarlos por medio del posicionamiento. Claramente, lo hice mal

Comment: A ver si entiendo bien, suponiendo que hay un numero de 2 digitos, `ab`, entonces hay que buscar un numero tal que `ab` = `2*(a*b)`?

Comment: sip, asi es 
un ejemplo 
36 = (3 * 6) * 2

pero mi problema es que no se como separar lo digitos:
10 = 1 , 0
11 = 1, 1
12 = 1, 2

y asi sucesivamente para poder aplicar mi formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leyendo los comentarios, una forma numérica (sin usar cadenas) de implementar esa lógica sería con 2 ciclos `for`; uno recorrerá las decenas y el de más adentro las unidades:

```
for i in range(1, 10): # Decenas
    for j in range(0, 10): # Unidades
        num = i*10 + j # <-- Aqui se unen ambas cifras
        if num == 2*i*j:
            print(num)
```

Otra forma es al contrario, con un solo `for` y descomponiendo los dígitos:

```
for num in range(10, 100): 
    i = num % 10 # Unidad
    j = num // 10 # Decena
    if num == 2*i*j:
        print(num)
```

El 10 al 99 unicamente cumple el 3 y 6, `36`

Comment: También podrías usar [divmod](https://docs.python.org/es/3.10/library/functions.html#divmod). Ejemplo `j, i = divmod(num, 10)`

Comment: Muchas gracias! lo voy a probar :D